# How to add in swift spring animation to an image?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewanimation

I have already made the lay-out for the image. So I don't have any CGPoint x and y values. [Storyboard picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JIUz.png)
As you can see on the picture, I made 5 circles and one main circle. I want to make these 5 circles come from behind the main circle as the user open the app. I did a lot of research and I found that I can use the spring animation method because it seems more realistic with physics and so on. However, it just didn't work out.

First I change the center of the circle1 and send it to the backside of the main circle (which didn't work) Because of the failure the circle doesn't come up from the behind.

I am not sure why I couldn't change the position of the circle. Is it because I already made the lay-out?

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainCircle: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var circle1: UIImageView!



override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
```

self.circle1.center = self.mainCircle.center

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.5, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: [] , animations: {
        self.circle1.center = CGPointMake(160, 219)
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Please help me with this. 
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Set options parameter to `[]`, this will set options to nothing in your spring animation.

---

For your animations, put this line:

`self.circle1.center = self.mainCircle.center`

Inside of `viewDidLoad()` method.

Then, in your spring animation, change the code so the position is calculated using relative position to the mainCirle, not fixed values. Like so:

```
self.circle1.center = CGPointMake(self.mainCircle.center.x-75, self.mainCircle.center.x-75)
```

You can change this point to be in whatever direction you want your circle to be in from the main circle.

---

Complete code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.circle1.center = self.mainCircle.center
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.5, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: [] , animations: {
        self.circle1.center = CGPointMake(self.mainCircle.center.x-75, self.mainCircle.center.x-75)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you so much. But I still can't move the object. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're animating when the view loads, make sure you're animating in `viewDidAppear` method, not `viewDidLoad` method because in viewDidLoad it will happen before the view is shown. If this doesn't work can you show more code, eg when you're calling it and the rest of your code?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't understand why it didn't work out. I'm edited the question so that I can show you my whole code. Can you check it again? First I want to center all little circles behind the main circle and when the user open the app, the I want the little circles go their original places, which I made auto lay-out before. Thank you so much.

Comment: @BuckyAk When you say it doesn't work, do you mean it doesn't animate or it doesn't move to the new position at all?

Comment: It doesn't change the position. I mean at first it should be behind the main circle because before animation code I wrote self.circle1.center = self.mainCircle.center. Then surprisingly little circle comes from the opposite direction. I mean it should come from the main circle but it comes from upside. I didn't even write the code for coming up.

Comment: @BuckyAk Please see edits. You need to put the line that puts the circle1 in the centre of mainCircle in viewDidLoad method so the animation happens, the circle will be in the centre of mainCircle

Answer (score 0):

There's a really useful library to simplify Spring animations that's worth looking into. You can download it below:

https://github.com/MengTo/Spring

I have lots of animations in my apps and this makes it really easy. You'd probably want to set all the circles to the centre then change their x,y and use animateTo().

Answer (score 0):

```
    let identityAnimation = CGAffineTransform.identity
    let scaleOfIdentity = identityAnimation.scaledBy(x: 0.001, y: 0.001)
    slideActionComponentCollectionView.transform = scaleOfIdentity
    self.addSubview(slideActionComponentCollectionView)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3/1.5, animations: {
        let scaleOfIdentity = identityAnimation.scaledBy(x: 1.1, y: 1.1)
        self.slideActionComponentCollectionView.transform = scaleOfIdentity
    }, completion: {finished in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3/2, animations: {
            let scaleOfIdentity = identityAnimation.scaledBy(x: 0.9, y: 0.9)
            self.slideActionComponentCollectionView.transform = scaleOfIdentity
        }, completion: {finished in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3/2, animations: {
                self.slideActionComponentCollectionView.transform = identityAnimation
            })
        })
    })
```